# Как конвертировать строку в json объект, с которым можно будет взаимодействовать

Tags: c#

Прилетает мне значит ответ в формате **`["RU_2043042304"]`**, значение цифр плавающее, то есть могут быть и другие цифры.

Пытался сделать вот таким методом

```
var responseJsonMID = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserMatch[]>(responseMID);
```

Но проблема в том, что в класс `UserMatch` я не могу вписать название, так как не знаю цифр нужных.

В конечном результате я должен получить из  `["RU_85984958"] -> RU_85984958`

Comment: `DeserializeObject<string[]>(…)`?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

```
DeserializeObject<string[]>(…)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/822785)

Comment: @NowhereMan ответов кроме этого нет.

Comment: @NowhereMan С радостью, если бы тут был ответ кроме моего ;/